# How to enable the GamePad feature for WKWebView in iOS?

Tags: ios, wkwebview, gamepad-api

I looked for the documentation, but I couldn't find the API.
But I have tested Chrome for the iOS version, it is fine.
I don't know how to enable it. Who can tell me, thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but once you move around a stick or hit a button an even calls the brwoser, which should ask the user for permission

Comment: GamePad is H5 standard API. i sure it be disabled in WKWebView. I use the other way to solve this problem

Comment: It should be enabled as of iOS 13 according to this [comment](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205448#c3) by an Apple WebKit engineer on the bug tracker.

Comment: In the end, I use the ios gamepad API to fetch the data and post it th WKWebView